# Django permissions: custom logic-based checks

Tags: django, permissions, authorization

Simplified example:

```
# foo/models.py
class Bar(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

# foo/views.py
class BarEditView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'foo.change_bar'
    model = Bar
    success_url = '/'
```

I want the BarEditView to be accessible by:

1. users who have `foo.change_bar` permission in the database (already accomplished by the first line of that class)
2. the author of that particular Bar record

The first is easily handled by basic permissions/groups. How do I achieve the second? I need to write some custom permission check logic, but I can't find anything in the docs or google. I don't want to have to "manually" add a permission to the database every time a Bar author is set/changed/removed.

To be clear, I am not asking how to *create* a "custom permission". I want am trying to augment the logic for determining who has permission.

Comment: UserPassesTestMixin looks promising. I'll report back after trying that.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, `django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin` is what I needed!

```
# foo/models.py
class Bar(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

# foo/views.py
class BarEditView(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Bar
    success_url = '/'
    
    def test_func(self):
        if self.request.user.has_perm('foo.change_bar'):
            return True
        elif self.request.user == self.get_object().author:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```